# Priority of the Nougat sound control

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

Is there any way I can change the priority of the Nougat sound control?

Every time I click the volume button on the side of my smartphone it prioritizes the volume of notifications.

The priority for my smartphone is as follows:

1. Notifications
2. Alarm
3. Media

And I would like to switch to:

1. Media
2. Notifications
3. Alarm

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this with stock Android.  There may be OEM (Samsung, LG, etc) features that allow this but I'm unsure if they exist.

There is an app that allows you to lock Media Volume, though.  It's called *Rocker Locker:*
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomwandroid.rockerlocker&hl=en

[Edit]  The above app reports significant battery drain.  This app may be a better alternative, *NGC 4388:*
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=catchpower.gogo.blackholeaddons

Of course, there's always the option of writing your own volume panel changes then compiling your own OS binary from source.  :)